# Error: Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have cursor initialized as follows:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //...Code, code, code...

        c = db.query("US_States", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);


    }
```

The cursor itself is used in a separate method within the same activity:

```
public void GameStart()
    {
        int gameCount = 0;
        while(gameCount < 5)
        {
            cursorEntry = new Random().nextInt(c.getCount());
            c.moveToPosition(cursorEntry);
            cursorState = c.getString(1);
            cursorCapital = c.getString(2);
            displayText.setText(cursorState);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
E/CursorWindow﹕ Failed to read row 20, column 2 from a CursorWindow which has 50 rows, 2 columns.
```

With a stack trace pointing at this line `cursorCapital = c.getString(2);` every time I rerun the application. It always gives an error there.

The database something like this:

```
State|Capital
Alabama|Montgomery
Alaska|Juneau
Arizona|Phoenix
...The rest of the states
```

I read a couple of similar posts on SO, but they didn't give me an idea of what is going wrong. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The column index of a cursor is zero-based, so change:

```
 cursorState = c.getString(1);
 cursorCapital = c.getString(2);
```

to

```
cursorState = c.getString(0);
cursorCapital = c.getString(1);
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks. Didn't know it counts columns from 0.