# How to display the data in table view in android eclipse

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
public void Showdata(View view)
    {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Student2", null);
        int count = c.getCount();
        c.moveToFirst();
        TableLayout tablelayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
        tablelayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        TableRow tablerow;
        TextView textview, textview1, textview3, textview5;
        tablerow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

        textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textview.setText("Name");
        textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textview.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        tablerow.addView(textview);


        textview5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textview5.setText("Email");
        textview5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textview5.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textview5.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        tablerow.addView(textview5);
        tablelayout.addView(tablerow);

        for(Integer j=0; j< count; j++)
        {
            tablerow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

            textview1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textview1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(name)));


            textview3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textview3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(email)));

            textview1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textview3.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

            tablerow.addView(textview1);
            tablerow.addView(textview3);

            tablelayout.addView(tablerow);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        setContentView(tablelayout);
        db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code with some dummy students, it is working fine for me.

Please verify that you are getting students by iterating the cursor. Put some `Log.d("tag","some_student")` for testing

Also, You should use **YourActivityName.this** in place of **getApplicationContext()**. For example

```
tablerow = new TableRow(this);
```

Full Code using the dummy students

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        students.add(new Student("Rahul","rahul@gmail.com"));
        students.add(new Student("Shweta","shweta@gmail.com"));
        students.add(new Student("Test","test@gmail.com"));
        students.add(new Student("Mohan","mohan@gmail.com"));


        TableLayout tablelayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tablelayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        TableRow tablerow;
        TextView textview, textview1, textview3, textview5;
        tablerow = new TableRow(this);

        textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Name");
        textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textview.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        tablerow.addView(textview);


        textview5 = new TextView(this);
        textview5.setText("Email");
        textview5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textview5.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textview5.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        tablerow.addView(textview5);
        tablelayout.addView(tablerow);

        for(Integer j=0; j< students.size(); j++)
        {
            tablerow = new TableRow(this);

            textview1 = new TextView(this);
            textview1.setText(students.get(j).getName());


            textview3 = new TextView(this);
            textview3.setText(students.get(j).getEmail());

            textview1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textview3.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

            tablerow.addView(textview1);
            tablerow.addView(textview3);

            tablelayout.addView(tablerow);
        }
        setContentView(tablelayout);

    }

    class Student {
        String name;
        String email;

        public Student(String name, String email) {
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Dear Did you try that on real Device or AVD Manager, actually when i'm trying that on my AVD manager then it's not working, the message is "Application name Unfortunately has stop working", now what should i do for that and this problem remain same with some another application

Comment: Above code will work on both emulator or real device. If you are getting message saying "Unfortunately app has stopped", it means your app is crashing due to some exception. Check your logs using logcat in eclipse and you'll get to know exception. You can paste your stack trace so that I can help you.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Could not execute method for android:onClick

Comment: Paste your full activity code and stack trace. The information that you have given is not sufficient to solve your problem.

Comment: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 6 rows, 3 columns.Shutting down VM
beginning of crash
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.simplesqlite, PID: 2216
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)

Comment: at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
9 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)at com.simplesqlite.MainActivity.Showdata(MainActivity.java:82)
11 more

Comment: Seems like you have problem with the cursor. Read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178441/error-make-sure-the-cursor-is-initialized-correctly-before-accessing-data-from)

Comment: okay i'm trying new example if the problem is remain same then i'll tell you,